# CakePHP submit form with validation problem

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

```
    echo $this->Form->create('Comment', 
            array('url'=>array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' =>'add', $listposts['Post']['id']) )
            );

    echo $this->Form->input('post_id',array('type'=>'hidden','style'=>'width:30%','value'=>$listposts['Post']['id']));  
    echo $this->Form->input('name',array('style'=>'width:30%'));
    echo $this->Form->input('email',array('style'=>'width:30%'));   
    echo $this->Form->input('body',array('rows'=>'5'));

    echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

If any of that three fields is empty it's still saving data into table. How can i stop saving data if one input field is empty. But the column of comments table is not null.

```
mysql> describe comments;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body     | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment model =>

```
<?php
class Comment extends AppModel {

    var $useTable='comments';
    var $belongsTo = array('Post');

}
```

Model with validation but it's not displaying any message , but it doesn't save data.

```
post<?php
class Comment extends AppModel {

  var $useTable='comments';
  var $belongsTo = array('Post');

  var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Enter Name.'
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Enter Email.'
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Enter Body.'
    )
  );


}
```

Comment: refer this link http://book.cakephp.org/view/1143/Data-Validation

Comment: I edited the original post or question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Model

```
<?php
class Comment extends AppModel {

var $useTable='comments';
var $belongsTo = array('Post');



var $validate = array(
'name' => array(
    'rule' => array('maxLength' , 80),
    'required' => true,
    'message' => 'Please enter your name'
),
'body' =>  array(
    'rule' => array('maxLength' , 80),
    'required' => true,
    'message' => 'Please enter your body'
),

'email' => array(
    'rule' => 'email',
    'required' => true,
    'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address.'
),

);

}

     ?>
```

Comment: I got error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' for line  'rule' => array('maxLength' , 80),

Comment: I have edited the original post/question with validation. But if any input field is empty it's still staying in same page. But it's not saving any data as one field is empty. But it's not displaying any message.

Comment: for desplay message,refer this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529023/structuring-a-cakephp-registration-page/6544913#6544913

Comment: try it with  echo $this->Session->flash();

Answer (score 4):

In your controller Add these line and then check what is the error displaying.. i think surly it will work properly. with empty fields u submit a form error will display

```
$this->Comment->set($this->data);

if ($this->Comment->validates())
{
      if ($this->Comment->save($this->data))
      {
       $this->Session->setFlash('Comment  saved ', 'default'));
      }
      else
      {
          var_dump($this->Comment->invalidFields());
            //OR
           $this->Comment->validationErrors();
      }


}
else
{
   var_dump($this->Comment->invalidFields());
    //OR
    $this->Comment->validationErrors();


}
```